# get_terms() parent, child and grandchild

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, categories

parent1 - child1 - grandchild1

I need to show child terms of any current term (only direct child) for each term I visit.
Works only for the parent (show child1) but not for the child (doesn't show granchild1)

How I can fix this issue? Thank's

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$cpt = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

echo 'cpt - '.$cpt;
echo '<br>tax - '.$taxonomy;
echo '<br>term id - '.$term_id;

$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($cpt);
if ( $customPostTaxonomies ) {

     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax) {
         $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'hierarchical' => 0,
              'taxonomy' => $tax,
              'field' => 'id',
              'parent'=> $term_id,
              'title_li' => ''
              );
         wp_list_categories( $args );
     }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Structure:
cpt = corsi
tax = argomenti
tax_term = parent1
tax_term_child = child1
tax_term_child_granchild = grandchild1
```

Comment: You're trying to show multiple taxonomies using the term from one taxonomy - can you confirm you just want to show all immediate child terms of the *current* taxonomy term?

Comment: Thank's for reply. I've updated the request. This fuction have to be on taxonomy.php  and work for all taxonomy page. And YES, I want to show all immediate child terms of the current taxonomy term.
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for a taxonomy archive, you can just use `get_queried_object()` and  the `parent` and `depth` argument in `wp_list_categories()`:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$list = wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
    'parent'   => $term->term_id,
    'title_li' => '',
    'depth'    => 1,
    'echo'     => false,
));

if ( $list ) {
    echo "<ul>$list</ul>";
} else {
    // Nothing, do something else!
}
```

Note that `wp_list_categories()` does not output/return a containing `<ul />`, so you need to do so yourself (as demonstrated).

Comment: Thank's for help but don't work. When i'm on the child1 page it show me "no category" and not "grandchild1"

Comment: Works for me - I had three categories "Parent", "Child", "Grandchild", have made sure there is at least one post attached to each. Go to "Parent" archive, see "Child". Go to "Child" archive, see "Grandchild". Go to "Grandchild" archive, see nothing (as expected, term has no children).

Comment: I can confirm the your solution works! Thank's for your time.

ps. There isn't a way to show the term also if is empty ?? Thank's for your time.

Comment: You can add an `else` if there are no terms to show, see revision.

Comment: if empy, with else [ echo 'something'; }, it show me "no category" and not the echo

Comment: SOLVED - adding    'show_option_none' => __(''),  to the array no more "no category" print. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR TIME, have a nice day.